# Is there a way to get the url of the page from which an image is being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am allowing a drag and drop functionality in my application where i am allowing users to drag and drop images from other sites. I can get the url of the image being dragged. But is there a way to get the url of the page from which the image is being dragged with jquery? Does the dataTransfer method contain any such node ?

Comment: In a word, no.  You'll have to come up with an alternative way if you want the page URL, like asking them for it and then showing them all the images from that page so they can choose one.  You still get the functionality, but the page URL as well.

Comment: i wonder then how google does it when an image from any other site is dragged to the google image search!

Comment: What makes you think it does?

Comment: Well i guess i misinterpreted it .. I was tampering the requests captured from the google image search and got the url. didnt quite look through it before. Appears it not the url of the page but the url of the image itself.

Comment: Bear in mind that the source of the image may not be a web page.  It could be a local folder on your computer.